# For loop subtraction issue in c

Tags: c, for-loop, subtraction

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int a , b, i , sum = 0 ;
printf("\a");
 printf("\n\t\t What is the number you want to begin"               
        " subtraction with ?   ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
     printf("\n\t\t What is the number you want to end"
            " subtraction with ?   ");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    
      printf("\a");
      printf("\n\t\t The result of the subtraction of numbers from %d to %d :\n"
      , a , b);
      printf("\t\t   ");
      for (i = a ; i >= b+1 ; i--){
        printf("%d - ", i);
        sum = sum - i ;
      printf("%d = %d\n\n", b , sum);
      return 0;
     }
```

I want to create a program that subtracts a sequence of numbers from a to b using a for loop in C programming language. I tried for many times, and couldn't find a solution. I want a program that runs like this: for example, if I chose (a) as 8 and (b) as 5, I want the program to write `8-7-6-5 = -10`. I want a program that runs like that depending on the value I choose as (a) and (b) using a for loop in c programming.

Comment: You're missing `;` at the end of the `return 0` statement

Comment: What is the logic? Why is it `8-6-5` not `8-7-6-5`?

Comment: 'if I chose (a) as 8 and (b) as 5 , I want the program to write 8-6-5 = -3' .....where did the '6' come from?

Comment: @MartinJames I think he wants to subtract all the numbers between a and b, but he forgot 7

Comment: Indent your code properly please. This is barely readable.

Comment: Yes ,I wanted 8-7-6-5 ... I forgot the 7 .

Answer (score 1):

> if I chose (a) as 8 and (b) as 5, I want the program to write 8-6-5 = -3

I believe that you forgot about number `7` and it should be `8-7-6-5 = -10`

If yes:

```
int myfunc(int start, int end)
{
    int result = start;
    for(int index = start - 1; index >= end; index--)
    {
        result -= index;
    }
    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    printf("%d", myfunc(8,5));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6133cjbK1

If you want to print the  whole expression:

```
int myfunc(int start, int end)
{
    int result = start;
    printf("%d", start);
    for(int index = start - 1; index >= end; index--)
    {
        printf("-%d", index);
        result -= index;
    }
    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    printf("=%d", myfunc(8,5));
}
```

Comment: This solution would print `-10`, but would not print `8-7-6-5 = `  as required by the question.

Comment: @JonathonS. happy now?

Comment: Ok , but what is the code needed to subtract a sequence of numbers from the largest number to the lowest number ? (e.g.. If I chose a as 10 and b as 8 , I want the program to execute 10-9-8 = -7